# Implement UISearchController with table view initially hidden in Swift iOS 9

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview, uisearchcontroller, ios9.3

I am trying to implement search bar in a view which would display filtered info as typed in the search bar dynamically in a table view. Also table view should initially be hidden until user doesn't starts typing. I have searched for the same but all I got was search controller embeded in table view header where table view is already there with some other info to display. Following image is what I have tried so far[image]

Underlying is a mapview therefor I am unable to set table view initially shown

Answer (score 1):

Show the table in the `searchBarShouldBeginEditing` method.

```
func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
    //Currently Table is hidden
    table.alpha = 0
    table.isHidden = false
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) { 
        self.table.alpha = 1
    }
    return true
}
```

Note: this is in Swift 3 :)

Comment: but search bar is added in table view header.

Comment: I do not believe you can hide the tableview, but show the search bar. I suggest taking it out. It may be a hassle at first, but it will be helpful later on.